# Will "Temporarily Work Uncontrolled" allow me to retain VSS source control safely?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

If I *move a solution to another computer,* and select the `Temporarily Work Uncontrolled` option from the SourceSafe plugin, can I move the project back to the original computer (deleting the original solution on the original computer and replacing it with my "temporarily work uncontrolled" copy of the solution), and expect it to re-sync with SourceSafe and incorporate all of my changes?

Or is this too dangerous to attempt?

Comment: SourceSafe? Truly, I feel the pain.

Comment: I don't use SS, but I use perforce with the VSS plugin.  My conclusion is that the plugin is worthless. I always work "uncontrolled" and simply check in files once I am done with a discrete amount of work.  The plugin seems to require more effort on my part than a simple checkout/change/checkin workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my personal experience, I know that you'll be going through all sorts of weirdness. VSS will refuse to sync some files at all and will give conflict errors for some others. Also if you were to add any new projects to the solution, they wouldn't be synced when you copy the solution back.

My personal advice would be to work uncontrolled on another machine and create a .patch file (or any type of .diff file for that matter) when you're done and bring that over and apply it back to the original solution. Downside is that all the changes will appear in a single changeset.

Comment: I don't mind the changes being in one changeset but, er... What is a .patch file?  Is that a Windows Installer thing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - `.patch` files are a subversion type of file - it is like a unified diff. Not sure why it is mentioned in the context of VSS.

Comment: Nothing special, just a diff file created with your favorite diff/merge tool. My personal fav is [CodePlex SCC](http://codeplexclient.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToAcceptContributions&ProjectName=codeplexclient) which generates .patch files as a result of the diff run.